# Multiple levels of parallelization with scikit-learn

Tags: python, parallel-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am using scikit-learn's [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) on a multi-core sever to fit a large dataset so I am taking advantage of its parallelization feature by setting `n_jobs = -1`.

Simultaneously, I want to perform cross-validation (with [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score)) and make use of its parallelization feature as well (again, by setting `n_jobs = -1`).

My questions is whether using *both* types of parallelization will increase the speed of model construction significantly, more than using only a *single* type of parallelization. If the latter is true, then I am not sure which type of parallelization I should prefer. The scikit-learn documentation and SO do not offer any thoughts on how to make both types of parallelization work together.

Please let me know if I can provide you with any more information about my setup if it would be useful to provide a more helpful answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why not experiment timing with a subsample of your data?

Comment: Won't the `cross_val_score` be performed *after* the model is fitted?

Comment: No, there is a loop over folds within which fit is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only one type of parallelization will be used. It is not possible to nest joblib calls. I think the outermost loop will be used, that is `cross_val_score` but I'm not sure.

Which loop you should actually parallelize depends a bit on your setup. I would probably go for RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1) and do cross_val_score serially. With a verbose GridSearchCV that will also very quickly give you some insights into the validation accuracy.

Say instead you do the cross_val_score in parallel, and you have few folds compared to CPUs (say 5 folds and 5 CPUs). Usually some forests will take much shorter time than others, if you search over max-depth for example.
Then the quick forests will finish their job, and the CPU will be idle, while the "slow" forest will still be training.